# The $2$-norm of $A^*A$ is equal to the square of the norm of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

> Show that $\|A^*A\|_2 = (\|A\|_2)^2$, where  $A^*$ is the tranpose of $A$.

My approach: $$\|A^*A\|_2 = \sqrt{\lambda_{\max} [(A^*A)^*(A^*A)]}= \lambda_{\max} (A^*A)=\|A\|_2^2$$
It that right?

Comment: I formatted the post; please check the formulas are correct. Also, see the [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/). The proof appears correct, but it is missing justifications. Some words justifying the equalities claimed would help.